# Bootstrap 4 scrollbars on 2 divs side-by-side fixed and fluid width

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dashboard

I am trying to design a simple dashboard page.

I started with putting together two divs side by side to be used as side menu and content. The page looks like the following:

[image]

I noticed something that the scrollbar(y) isn't visible even though the page has more content than what is visible.

Yes you still can scroll down/up but it is confusing why there is no scrollbar visible.

I am trying to use bootstrap 4, but I also have a custom css.

What do you think the issue? And more importantly, is there a better way using bootstrap 4?

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dashboard Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #sideMenu {
        height: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #222D32;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #mainContents {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0px;
        left: 250px;            
        background-color: #ECF0F5;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #contentBody {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sideMenu">

    </div>

    <div id="mainContents">
        <div id="contentBody">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>                
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec euismod nisl, in mattis purus. Donec finibus luctus libero, sed lobortis elit maximus non. Quisque vitae venenatis odio, in dictum nibh. Sed suscipit nisi a bibendum tincidunt. Donec vestibulum lorem id bibendum hendrerit. Etiam ligula urna, porta gravida nisl non, ullamcorper venenatis dolor. Fusce ex nunc, lobortis at risus in, sollicitudin congue tellus. Pellentesque lacinia nibh id massa laoreet, ut aliquam urna iaculis. In mollis lobortis enim. Etiam pretium libero in elit posuere ornare. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris quis vulputate quam, et dignissim ante. Integer vitae auctor erat, vitae congue augue. In hendrerit et felis ac consequat.</p>
                <p>Sed ante nibh, molestie dignissim neque sit amet, elementum luctus felis. Duis hendrerit quam vel leo convallis facilisis. Vivamus id efficitur sem. In rutrum luctus arcu, at malesuada augue auctor id. Praesent a dui et diam sodales rhoncus ut at purus. Mauris vel tincidunt justo. Sed et ultricies tortor. Pellentesque sollicitudin lacus nisl, et finibus orci lobortis a. Quisque facilisis, mauris et scelerisque placerat, enim magna lacinia mauris, quis vestibulum sapien odio ut est. Maecenas ipsum augue, tristique vitae arcu nec, laoreet bibendum mauris. Morbi pretium elit in elit viverra egestas. Nunc quis sapien ipsum. Pellentesque efficitur lorem nec dui convallis, ut congue lorem aliquam. Morbi non sem lacinia, semper libero in, efficitur risus. Integer congue, metus non vehicula euismod, felis nisl viverra ipsum, at dignissim nibh eros ac eros.</p>
                <p>Cras vel pretium quam, ac sodales sapien. In ut laoreet turpis, at vestibulum metus. Aliquam gravida elementum consequat. Curabitur sagittis, massa cursus vestibulum cursus, eros sem sodales tortor, eu lacinia risus lectus ut augue. Quisque nec dui turpis. Maecenas imperdiet auctor quam, a condimentum nulla pulvinar sed. Cras a lacus id justo facilisis tristique in non turpis.</p>
                <p>Integer sit amet ipsum interdum metus scelerisque tempor. Sed pretium semper scelerisque. Etiam lacus dolor, tempor id aliquet egestas, porttitor a ante. Nam tincidunt mi id tellus bibendum, ac accumsan dolor bibendum. Donec placerat porttitor sagittis. Ut vitae vehicula orci. Aenean viverra sem a tellus rhoncus placerat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque quis metus sed lacus scelerisque posuere. Cras elementum, dolor ut elementum placerat, urna nisl aliquam eros, in pharetra diam massa quis leo. Pellentesque efficitur egestas pulvinar. Aliquam hendrerit diam in vulputate fringilla. In vitae nisl massa. Sed suscipit nisl ac quam molestie pharetra. Fusce scelerisque ultricies felis non vulputate.</p>
                <p>Nullam non consectetur diam. Nunc non rutrum ante. Aenean vestibulum metus ultricies diam fermentum fringilla. Ut efficitur tincidunt varius. Donec facilisis purus eget diam maximus efficitur. Proin aliquam eu metus id euismod. Nunc sed urna blandit metus bibendum elementum. Fusce lacinia tellus eu accumsan accumsan. Nullam ornare lacus quam, vitae sagittis velit mollis eget. Quisque et suscipit ante. In pulvinar ex vitae risus lacinia, vitae egestas neque interdum. Mauris enim leo, porta at risus at, ornare tincidunt sapien. Sed semper enim eleifend elit dictum, id fermentum sapien ullamcorper. Nam vitae urna a libero dapibus tempus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
                <p>Sed ante nibh, molestie dignissim neque sit amet, elementum luctus felis. Duis hendrerit quam vel leo convallis facilisis. Vivamus id efficitur sem. In rutrum luctus arcu, at malesuada augue auctor id. Praesent a dui et diam sodales rhoncus ut at purus. Mauris vel tincidunt justo. Sed et ultricies tortor. Pellentesque sollicitudin lacus nisl, et finibus orci lobortis a. Quisque facilisis, mauris et scelerisque placerat, enim magna lacinia mauris, quis vestibulum sapien odio ut est. Maecenas ipsum augue, tristique vitae arcu nec, laoreet bibendum mauris. Morbi pretium elit in elit viverra egestas. Nunc quis sapien ipsum. Pellentesque efficitur lorem nec dui convallis, ut congue lorem aliquam. Morbi non sem lacinia, semper libero in, efficitur risus. Integer congue, metus non vehicula euismod, felis nisl viverra ipsum, at dignissim nibh eros ac eros.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec euismod nisl, in mattis purus. Donec finibus luctus libero, sed lobortis elit maximus non. Quisque vitae venenatis odio, in dictum nibh. Sed suscipit nisi a bibendum tincidunt. Donec vestibulum lorem id bibendum hendrerit. Etiam ligula urna, porta gravida nisl non, ullamcorper venenatis dolor. Fusce ex nunc, lobortis at risus in, sollicitudin congue tellus. Pellentesque lacinia nibh id massa laoreet, ut aliquam urna iaculis. In mollis lobortis enim. Etiam pretium libero in elit posuere ornare. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris quis vulputate quam, et dignissim ante. Integer vitae auctor erat, vitae congue augue. In hendrerit et felis ac consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“What do you think the issue?”_ - the issue is that you have positioned both elements `fixed`, which takes them out of normal flow, so that they do not influence the height of their parent any more ...

Comment: It doesn't look like you're trying to use Bootstrap 4 at all. Why are both DIVs fixed? What is the exact layout are you trying to get? A fixed left sidebar and scrolling content?

Comment: @CBroe, I didn't know about this, thank you very much

Comment: @ZimSystem, yes I didn't actually use Bootstrap because I don't know how .. The layout I want is the one on the picture which I have with a visible right scrollbar (y) when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a simpler, Bootstrap friendly method...

https://www.codeply.com/go/y4HsWA8VA2

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar col">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="main col">
            ..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
}

.main {
    padding-left: 265px;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I have to margin them if I want to use nav bar?

Comment: No, just make sure you pad the top of the body as needed. I updated the demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/y4HsWA8VA2

Comment: Thank you! It worked very well. I should be able to take it from here

Answer (score 1):

scroll is not visible because you are giving width 100% of body and also pushing div 250px right side and also giving padding to right 250px;

so mainly content is overflowing to right side.

you have to do like

```
#mainContents {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0px;
        background-color: #ECF0F5;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
```

It will solve your Problem

Comment: Welcome and Thanks to your for accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from #mainContents style

```
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 250px;
```

Then your style will be like this

```
  <style>
    #sideMenu {
        height: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #222D32;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #mainContents {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0px;
        left: 250px;            
        background-color: #ECF0F5;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #contentBody {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

Code of whole page ia as follows. Please check it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dashboard Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #sideMenu {
        height: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #222D32;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #mainContents {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0px;
        left: 250px;            
        background-color: #ECF0F5;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #contentBody {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sideMenu">

    </div>

    <div id="mainContents">
        <div id="contentBody">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>                
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec euismod nisl, in mattis purus. Donec finibus luctus libero, sed lobortis elit maximus non. Quisque vitae venenatis odio, in dictum nibh. Sed suscipit nisi a bibendum tincidunt. Donec vestibulum lorem id bibendum hendrerit. Etiam ligula urna, porta gravida nisl non, ullamcorper venenatis dolor. Fusce ex nunc, lobortis at risus in, sollicitudin congue tellus. Pellentesque lacinia nibh id massa laoreet, ut aliquam urna iaculis. In mollis lobortis enim. Etiam pretium libero in elit posuere ornare. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris quis vulputate quam, et dignissim ante. Integer vitae auctor erat, vitae congue augue. In hendrerit et felis ac consequat.</p>
                <p>Sed ante nibh, molestie dignissim neque sit amet, elementum luctus felis. Duis hendrerit quam vel leo convallis facilisis. Vivamus id efficitur sem. In rutrum luctus arcu, at malesuada augue auctor id. Praesent a dui et diam sodales rhoncus ut at purus. Mauris vel tincidunt justo. Sed et ultricies tortor. Pellentesque sollicitudin lacus nisl, et finibus orci lobortis a. Quisque facilisis, mauris et scelerisque placerat, enim magna lacinia mauris, quis vestibulum sapien odio ut est. Maecenas ipsum augue, tristique vitae arcu nec, laoreet bibendum mauris. Morbi pretium elit in elit viverra egestas. Nunc quis sapien ipsum. Pellentesque efficitur lorem nec dui convallis, ut congue lorem aliquam. Morbi non sem lacinia, semper libero in, efficitur risus. Integer congue, metus non vehicula euismod, felis nisl viverra ipsum, at dignissim nibh eros ac eros.</p>
                <p>Cras vel pretium quam, ac sodales sapien. In ut laoreet turpis, at vestibulum metus. Aliquam gravida elementum consequat. Curabitur sagittis, massa cursus vestibulum cursus, eros sem sodales tortor, eu lacinia risus lectus ut augue. Quisque nec dui turpis. Maecenas imperdiet auctor quam, a condimentum nulla pulvinar sed. Cras a lacus id justo facilisis tristique in non turpis.</p>
                <p>Integer sit amet ipsum interdum metus scelerisque tempor. Sed pretium semper scelerisque. Etiam lacus dolor, tempor id aliquet egestas, porttitor a ante. Nam tincidunt mi id tellus bibendum, ac accumsan dolor bibendum. Donec placerat porttitor sagittis. Ut vitae vehicula orci. Aenean viverra sem a tellus rhoncus placerat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque quis metus sed lacus scelerisque posuere. Cras elementum, dolor ut elementum placerat, urna nisl aliquam eros, in pharetra diam massa quis leo. Pellentesque efficitur egestas pulvinar. Aliquam hendrerit diam in vulputate fringilla. In vitae nisl massa. Sed suscipit nisl ac quam molestie pharetra. Fusce scelerisque ultricies felis non vulputate.</p>
                <p>Nullam non consectetur diam. Nunc non rutrum ante. Aenean vestibulum metus ultricies diam fermentum fringilla. Ut efficitur tincidunt varius. Donec facilisis purus eget diam maximus efficitur. Proin aliquam eu metus id euismod. Nunc sed urna blandit metus bibendum elementum. Fusce lacinia tellus eu accumsan accumsan. Nullam ornare lacus quam, vitae sagittis velit mollis eget. Quisque et suscipit ante. In pulvinar ex vitae risus lacinia, vitae egestas neque interdum. Mauris enim leo, porta at risus at, ornare tincidunt sapien. Sed semper enim eleifend elit dictum, id fermentum sapien ullamcorper. Nam vitae urna a libero dapibus tempus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
                <p>Sed ante nibh, molestie dignissim neque sit amet, elementum luctus felis. Duis hendrerit quam vel leo convallis facilisis. Vivamus id efficitur sem. In rutrum luctus arcu, at malesuada augue auctor id. Praesent a dui et diam sodales rhoncus ut at purus. Mauris vel tincidunt justo. Sed et ultricies tortor. Pellentesque sollicitudin lacus nisl, et finibus orci lobortis a. Quisque facilisis, mauris et scelerisque placerat, enim magna lacinia mauris, quis vestibulum sapien odio ut est. Maecenas ipsum augue, tristique vitae arcu nec, laoreet bibendum mauris. Morbi pretium elit in elit viverra egestas. Nunc quis sapien ipsum. Pellentesque efficitur lorem nec dui convallis, ut congue lorem aliquam. Morbi non sem lacinia, semper libero in, efficitur risus. Integer congue, metus non vehicula euismod, felis nisl viverra ipsum, at dignissim nibh eros ac eros.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec euismod nisl, in mattis purus. Donec finibus luctus libero, sed lobortis elit maximus non. Quisque vitae venenatis odio, in dictum nibh. Sed suscipit nisi a bibendum tincidunt. Donec vestibulum lorem id bibendum hendrerit. Etiam ligula urna, porta gravida nisl non, ullamcorper venenatis dolor. Fusce ex nunc, lobortis at risus in, sollicitudin congue tellus. Pellentesque lacinia nibh id massa laoreet, ut aliquam urna iaculis. In mollis lobortis enim. Etiam pretium libero in elit posuere ornare. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris quis vulputate quam, et dignissim ante. Integer vitae auctor erat, vitae congue augue. In hendrerit et felis ac consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't change anything

Comment: It's working properly for me, I had sent the whole code of the page. Please check it

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dashboard Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #sideMenu {
        height: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #222D32;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #mainContents {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0px;
        left: 250px;            
        background-color: #ECF0F5;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    #contentBody {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sideMenu">

    </div>

    <div id="mainContents">
        <div id="contentBody" style="height:600px;width:480px;overflow:auto;background-color:yellowgreen;color:white;scrollbar-base-color:gold;font-family:sans-serif;padding:10px;">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>                
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec euismod nisl, in mattis purus. Donec finibus luctus libero, sed lobortis elit maximus non. Quisque vitae venenatis odio, in dictum nibh. Sed suscipit nisi a bibendum tincidunt. Donec vestibulum lorem id bibendum hendrerit. Etiam ligula urna, porta gravida nisl non, ullamcorper venenatis dolor. Fusce ex nunc, lobortis at risus in, sollicitudin congue tellus. Pellentesque lacinia nibh id massa laoreet, ut aliquam urna iaculis. In mollis lobortis enim. Etiam pretium libero in elit posuere ornare. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris quis vulputate quam, et dignissim ante. Integer vitae auctor erat, vitae congue augue. In hendrerit et felis ac consequat.</p>
                <p>Sed ante nibh, molestie dignissim neque sit amet, elementum luctus felis. Duis hendrerit quam vel leo convallis facilisis. Vivamus id efficitur sem. In rutrum luctus arcu, at malesuada augue auctor id. Praesent a dui et diam sodales rhoncus ut at purus. Mauris vel tincidunt justo. Sed et ultricies tortor. Pellentesque sollicitudin lacus nisl, et finibus orci lobortis a. Quisque facilisis, mauris et scelerisque placerat, enim magna lacinia mauris, quis vestibulum sapien odio ut est. Maecenas ipsum augue, tristique vitae arcu nec, laoreet bibendum mauris. Morbi pretium elit in elit viverra egestas. Nunc quis sapien ipsum. Pellentesque efficitur lorem nec dui convallis, ut congue lorem aliquam. Morbi non sem lacinia, semper libero in, efficitur risus. Integer congue, metus non vehicula euismod, felis nisl viverra ipsum, at dignissim nibh eros ac eros.</p>
                <p>Cras vel pretium quam, ac sodales sapien. In ut laoreet turpis, at vestibulum metus. Aliquam gravida elementum consequat. Curabitur sagittis, massa cursus vestibulum cursus, eros sem sodales tortor, eu lacinia risus lectus ut augue. Quisque nec dui turpis. Maecenas imperdiet auctor quam, a condimentum nulla pulvinar sed. Cras a lacus id justo facilisis tristique in non turpis.</p>
                <p>Integer sit amet ipsum interdum metus scelerisque tempor. Sed pretium semper scelerisque. Etiam lacus dolor, tempor id aliquet egestas, porttitor a ante. Nam tincidunt mi id tellus bibendum, ac accumsan dolor bibendum. Donec placerat porttitor sagittis. Ut vitae vehicula orci. Aenean viverra sem a tellus rhoncus placerat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque quis metus sed lacus scelerisque posuere. Cras elementum, dolor ut elementum placerat, urna nisl aliquam eros, in pharetra diam massa quis leo. Pellentesque efficitur egestas pulvinar. Aliquam hendrerit diam in vulputate fringilla. In vitae nisl massa. Sed suscipit nisl ac quam molestie pharetra. Fusce scelerisque ultricies felis non vulputate.</p>
                <p>Nullam non consectetur diam. Nunc non rutrum ante. Aenean vestibulum metus ultricies diam fermentum fringilla. Ut efficitur tincidunt varius. Donec facilisis purus eget diam maximus efficitur. Proin aliquam eu metus id euismod. Nunc sed urna blandit metus bibendum elementum. Fusce lacinia tellus eu accumsan accumsan. Nullam ornare lacus quam, vitae sagittis velit mollis eget. Quisque et suscipit ante. In pulvinar ex vitae risus lacinia, vitae egestas neque interdum. Mauris enim leo, porta at risus at, ornare tincidunt sapien. Sed semper enim eleifend elit dictum, id fermentum sapien ullamcorper. Nam vitae urna a libero dapibus tempus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
                <p>Sed ante nibh, molestie dignissim neque sit amet, elementum luctus felis. Duis hendrerit quam vel leo convallis facilisis. Vivamus id efficitur sem. In rutrum luctus arcu, at malesuada augue auctor id. Praesent a dui et diam sodales rhoncus ut at purus. Mauris vel tincidunt justo. Sed et ultricies tortor. Pellentesque sollicitudin lacus nisl, et finibus orci lobortis a. Quisque facilisis, mauris et scelerisque placerat, enim magna lacinia mauris, quis vestibulum sapien odio ut est. Maecenas ipsum augue, tristique vitae arcu nec, laoreet bibendum mauris. Morbi pretium elit in elit viverra egestas. Nunc quis sapien ipsum. Pellentesque efficitur lorem nec dui convallis, ut congue lorem aliquam. Morbi non sem lacinia, semper libero in, efficitur risus. Integer congue, metus non vehicula euismod, felis nisl viverra ipsum, at dignissim nibh eros ac eros.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec euismod nisl, in mattis purus. Donec finibus luctus libero, sed lobortis elit maximus non. Quisque vitae venenatis odio, in dictum nibh. Sed suscipit nisi a bibendum tincidunt. Donec vestibulum lorem id bibendum hendrerit. Etiam ligula urna, porta gravida nisl non, ullamcorper venenatis dolor. Fusce ex nunc, lobortis at risus in, sollicitudin congue tellus. Pellentesque lacinia nibh id massa laoreet, ut aliquam urna iaculis. In mollis lobortis enim. Etiam pretium libero in elit posuere ornare. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris quis vulputate quam, et dignissim ante. Integer vitae auctor erat, vitae congue augue. In hendrerit et felis ac consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

you need to add css in div tag `style="height:600px;width:480px;overflow:auto;background-color:yellowgreen;color:white;scrollbar-base-color:gold;font-family:sans-serif;padding:10px;"`